# Load CSS file into child theme Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a child theme in Wordpress, I use this script to load my JS script in `functions.php`

```
function load_child_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( "main",get_template_directory_uri()."_child/scripts/main.js"); 
}
    add_action( "wp_footer", "load_child_js");
```

I want to do the same for my css file, I try to reproduce the same script but it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_enqueue_style` for your css.

```
wp_enqueue_style('mycss',get_template_directory_uri().'_child/css/main.css');
```

[Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

But instead of `wp_footer`, hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts`. You can also enqueue your script there, and if you want script to be in the footer, set 5th parameter to `true`. [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)